# numerical integration of experimental data

Tags: matlab

I am an undergraduate student and I am new to matlab. I need to do a numerical intergration without knowing the function. I have a 2D matrix with 75 rows and 365 columns which is equivalent to salinity values for everyday of the year in each of the 75 levels of depth (some of the last rows have NaN values). I also have an another matrix with 75 rows and one column which is the depth of every level, for example the first row has the value 0.005 which is the depth of the first level. How can I intergrate the data from the top of the sea till down the bottom and get one value of salinity of every day of the year? I understand that probably I will have to use the Trapezoidal numerical integration but if I use it, I end up with NaN values and if I exclude the NaN values I get very high values. (my values are not evenly spaced)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It sounds like you have tried something yourself, which is great. Can you post your attempt, what you got and what you expected/wanted. You will get more help this way than just saying what you want.

Comment: Yes, of course.


filename='TM_797_adri_S.nc'
ncdisp(filename)
dep=ncread(filename,'deptht')
vosaline=ncread(filename,'vosaline_n')
time=ncread(filename,'time_counter')
d=reshape(vosaline, [75,365])
k=d(~isnan(d(:, 1)), :)
Q=trapz(k)
figure
plot(Q)

The results are actually the sum of each column. Is that the function of trapz?